# I need to identify two characters in a Blue-White Porcelain Calligraphy

Tags: character-identification, calligraphy

Context. The porcelain is a large moon flat vase, from a private collection. The calligraphy is located inside a white rectangle, parallel to the mouth lip. The calligraphy is formed by 6 blue characters. I am sure that I correctly identified 5 of them. I am not sure of characters number 5 and 6, on the left side[image: Characters ordered]. I am not sure if due to the period of time they were made should they be read as they are 究旱徳宣明大, or in the modern way: 大明宣徳旱究. May be is a Ming Dynasty period vase. Please find attached some pictures and information.[image: Six blues characters numbered 1 to 6 from right to left]

[image: Large Moon Flat Vase Main View]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's 大明宣德年制（製) meaning "made in the years of 宣德 of the Ming dynasty".

Comment: Is what I read exactly.

Comment: if it is really 大明宣德年制（製), oh boy, that's a lot of money